# Authorizing soap c# request errors

Tags: soap, c#, authorization

https://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/api_overview/

In the above link it states "This element contains the customer's API username. A customer who uses the API creates a special user in ExactTarget that the API uses to log in. This user's password does not expire."

Is this API user the same user with credentials I use to log in with?

I have gone here: https://mc.s6.exacttarget.com/cloud/#app/Cloud%20Preferences

And the preferences state that the user I'm trying to login with is an API user but when I try to use the Soap API using the credentials I get this error: 
"Security requirements are not satisfied because the security header is not present in the incoming message."

Comment: I am getting the same error. I know my credentials are goods as they work for another API that was built from a third party